# 403 forbidden when retrieving data with pusher/javascript

Tags: javascript, http, pusher

I am using pusher to retrieve data/notifications from a channel. The data that I should be receiving is:

1. a username
2. the actual data
3. a link

I keep getting a 403 forbidden in my firebug console for the link and it is not being displayed on the UI.

The link had a trailing slash. I used the following function to remove it and then send it via pusher.

```
$user_photo = rtrim($this->twitter_model->getImage($u) , '/');
```

The 403 forbidden is still there. I can see the link in my firebug console though which means the function is working properly.

Any idea where i could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to bind to a private channel? If so, have you [authenticated](http://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users) first?

Comment: I am properly authenticated. Like i said, the other data are properly retrieve and displayed. Only the link cannot be retrieved.

Comment: can the link be obtained? as a 403 is provided from the server and by reading your Question it sounds like the link is being returned just the when you browse to it it's 403'ing if this is the case try browsing to the link in your browser normally if it is still 403ing there might be a problem with there server as 403 is a server side access is forbidden

Comment: It's a link to a twitter user's profile picture. It is not 403'ing when i browse it in my browser.

Comment: could you provide an output of the object returned and By the luck of your code is pusher php? if so can you just post a `echo "<pre>".print_r($this->twitter_model)."</pre>"; exit();`

Comment: Here is a screenshot: http://d.pr/i/90rw
And the link in question: http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2128173759/eightbit-6d22f234-4bc0-45ec-bb91-f82c1017c298_normal.png

Comment: @MartinBarker an echo provides the link just fine which is: http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2128173759/eightbit-6d22f234-4bc0-45ec-bb91-f82c1017c298_normal.png
I tried that already.

Comment: That is why there is a trailing slash on the end one min i will write and answer

Comment: The getimage function fetches the link from my cache database. The link does not even have a trailing slash in the end. I don't get why the trailing slash automatically appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function removeTrailingSlash($str){
    $str = str_split($str);
    $len = count($str)-1;
    if($str[$len] == '/'){
        unset($str[$len]);
    }
    return implode($str);
}
?>

$user_photo = removeTrailingSlash($this->twitter_model->getImage($u));
```

replace this with above

```
$user_photo = removeTrailingSlash(rtrim($this->twitter_model->getImage($u) , '/'));
```

Use that you should not be adding a trailing / on the end of a full filepath URL E.G ends in .png the only time you can do that is with .php/ and that's because the server has been told to allow it

Go to this 
http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2128173759/eightbit-6d22f234-4bc0-45ec-bb91-f82c1017c298_normal.png/

Then go to this
http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2128173759/eightbit-6d22f234-4bc0-45ec-bb91-f82c1017c298_normal.png

See the later works Trailing slash errors :)

Add the function to the top of the file and then let it use the new code

Comment: I have no idea why this worked but it did. In my javascript i retrieve the photo with the following variable: data.user_photo. I created a new variable like this var photo = ''+data.user_photo+ '' ; and it worked.

Comment: Your welcome however for the sake of google and other users please post your resolution as an Answer :)